# Wavelink - How do i send message when track has started?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently making a music bot and I don't know how to send a message when track has started. I have tried this, but doesn't work.

```
async def on_wavelink_track_start(player: wavelink.Player, track: wavelink.Track):

    Ctx = player.ctx
```

AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'ctx'.

I don't know what to do because the documentation doesn't say anything about this.

Version of llibraries I am using: Wavelink(1.3.5) and Discord.py(2.0).

Answer (score 0):

`Player` only has `guild` as an attribute, which isn't enough to send a message.

You can grab a `channel` object using its `id` and use that to send your message. The below assumes that your bot client is named `client` in your code.

```py
async def on_wavelink_track_start(player: wavelink.Player, track: wavelink.Track):
    channel = client.get_channel(123456789) # replace with correct channel id
    await channel.send('Message to send')
```

This is only if you want to use the `on_wavelink_track_start` event. You could always just send the message from the command that starts the process using `ctx` like normal.

Comment: It would be helpful if I can somehow save the last channel where the command was executed and send all messages there.

Comment: If you edit your question to include more of your code then I could probably help

Comment: I can't add anything more because that's all I have, there is no argument to get the previous context of the channel.

Comment: You said in your comment that you want to save the channel where the command was executed. So you can at the very least include the command. We can't help you if we don't see your code...